# Smooth scroll to review tab in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, tabs, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to install a smooth scroll for woocommerce and wordpress. There are a lot of plugins available. But all of them are not able to scroll to an anchor in a tab. In this special case I would like to have a smooth scroll when there is a click on the reviews (under the price). There is one plugin which can do this, but it needs two clicks. The first click opens the review tab, and when its open the anchor is on the same page as the link. Then the second click moves to the anchor. 
Is it possible to write a javascript capable to do that?